# Prove that the only operator on $\mathbb{C}$ for which his inner product is zero is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, inner-products

How do I prove this statement: Let $V$ be an unitary vector space over $\Bbb C$, $(,)$ be an inner product on $V$ and $\Bbb A$ operator $V\rightarrow V$. Then $(\Bbb Av,v)=0$ if and only if $\Bbb A=0$.

I know that on $\Bbb R$ this does not apply, since we are searching for an operator that assigns to my vector a vector that is orthogonal and so every orthogonal projection on a subspace of $\Bbb R$ can be this operator. But how is this possible on $\Bbb C$? Thank you.

Comment: Is C$=\Bbb C{}{}$? Is C$\neq \mathbf C$?

Comment: @Git Gud: C should be the set of complex numbers, I don't know how to format it. Resp. it should be V, an unitary subspace on complex numbers

Comment: Type \$\Bbb C\$ to get $\Bbb C$.

Comment: You probaby want to type \$A\$ instead of \$\Bbb A\$, in order to get $A$ instead of $\Bbb A$.

Comment: An orthogonal projection on $\Bbb R$ isn't a counterexample (look at vectors in the image). A $90^\circ$ rotation in the plane is.

Comment: @Git Gud in my textbook operators are also double letters, I am just quoting

Comment: @PseudoNeo yes, thank you, that is true

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This proof is (sort of) from *Advanced Linear Algebra* by Steven Roman.

Let $V$ be a complex inner product space and let $A$ be a linear operator on $V$ with the given property. For all $v\in V$ and $r\in\mathbb{C}$ we have
\begin{align}
0 &= \langle A(rv+Av),rv+Av \rangle \\
  &= |r|^2\langle Av,v\rangle + \langle A^2v,Av\rangle + r\langle Av, Av\rangle + \overline{r}\langle A^2 v, v\rangle \\
  &= r\langle Av, Av\rangle + \overline{r}\langle A^2 v, v\rangle.
\end{align}
Set $r=1$ to get
$$\langle Av, Av\rangle + \langle A^2 v, v\rangle=0,$$
and set $r=i$ to get
$$\langle Av, Av\rangle - \langle A^2 v, v\rangle=0.$$
Therefore $\Vert Av \Vert^2 = 0$.